# How to find empty array in a cell array in matlab?

Tags: matlab, cell-array, is-empty

My data has the following structure:

```
Cell_Array = {{[1]},{[]},{[8]}};
```

How can I find the empty array in this cell array without making a double loop?

This does not work. Since everything is not empty in this cell array.

```
~cellfun(@isempty,Cell_Array(:))
```

As you can see here:

```
isempty(Cell_Array{1,2})
ans = 0
```

It only works if:

```
isempty(Cell_Array{1,2}{1,1})
ans = 1
```

How can I solve this elegantly with `cellfun`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works without relying on the array having a specific structure. It gives a logical index with `true` for cells that contain `{[]}` and `false` for other cells.

```
result = cellfun(@(x)isequal(x,{[]}), Cell_Array);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
>> Cell_Array = {{[1]},{[]},{[8]}};
>> cellfun(@(x)isempty(x{:}),Cell_Array)
ans =
     0     1     0
```

Answer (score 1):

well, one way you can do assuming that all your data are like the one in your example is:

```
C =  [Cell_Array{:}];
~cellfun(@isempty,C(:))

ans =

 1
 0
 1
```